# With a Bridged ethernet connection to a virtual machine is the Host's firewall going to be passed through in-route to the vm's ip address?

Tags: windows, linux-networking, pxe-boot, tftp

Ok so some background: I have a linux virutal machine running a pxe server who's setup I copyied from my physical linux server that I setup in the past for booting a headless system. It works and still works to boot the headless device. I am now trying to use a virtual fedora on my win 10 laptop to do the pxe-boot operation. I am having trouble with the tftp read pxelinux.0 request getting through to my virutal machine though. the situtation is as follows:

1. Dhcpd server is up and giving the client linux system an ip address
2. client then moves on to request the file "pxelinux.0" at the tftp server ip 192.9.200.10
3. wireshark on windows host shows the tftp read request for pxelinux.0 dst ip 192.9.200.10
4. virtual machine wireshark on the bridged connection never sees the tftp read request.
5. client connection times out and boots to local harddrive

**My Question ** : IF you have a bridged ethernet connection and the client linux can see the virtual machines ip, do packets destined for the virtual machines ip pass through windows at all or through the windows firewall?

also I made sure the tftp.socket and service on the virtual linux were up and listening on port 69

```
systemctl status tftp
○ tftp.service - Tftp Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tftp.service; indirect; vendor pre>
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ● tftp.socket
       Docs: man:in.tftpd
lines 1-5/5 (END)
systemctl status tftp.socket
● tftp.socket - Tftp Server Activation Socket
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tftp.socket; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: active (listening) since Tue 2022-07-19 12:50:17 CDT; 23min ago
   Triggers: ● tftp.service
     Listen: [::]:69 (Datagram)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 11004)
     Memory: 4.0K
        CPU: 252us
     CGroup: /system.slice/tftp.socket

Jul 19 12:50:17 fedora systemd[1]: Listening on Tftp Server Activation Socket.
lines 1-11/11 (END)
ss -lu
State   Recv-Q  Send-Q    Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port  Process  
UNCONN  0       0               0.0.0.0:48494            0.0.0.0:*              
UNCONN  0       0         127.0.0.53%lo:domain           0.0.0.0:*              
UNCONN  0       0             127.0.0.1:323              0.0.0.0:*              
UNCONN  0       0               0.0.0.0:mdns             0.0.0.0:*              
UNCONN  0       0               0.0.0.0:hostmon          0.0.0.0:*              
UNCONN  0       0                     *:tftp                   *:*              
UNCONN  0       0                     *:tftp                   *:*              
UNCONN  0       0                 [::1]:323                 [::]:*              
UNCONN  0       0                  [::]:36714               [::]:*              
UNCONN  0       0                  [::]:mdns                [::]:*              
UNCONN  0       0                  [::]:hostmon             [::]:*
```

I have run the following commands on the virtual machine for the firewalld setting

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=tftp --permanent

firewall-cmd --add-service=dhcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --add-service=nfs --permanent
```

on the windows side when I run wireshark on the ethernet port I can see the tftp read request but it's destination is the virtual machines ip address which is the correct tftpboot server ip.

Comment: Active: inactive (dead) does not sound like a working service

Comment: It is inactive awaiting the trigger by the tftp.socket service , I thought the same thing at first and have done it with the service manually activated makes no difference. It is setup to be inactive until a tftp packet comes in on the socket program and the main service is triggered. Does it really help I'm not really convince it is in my case, I think it is more for a server running many many services at once.